# Does a spherical capacitor hold as much energy as a spherical shell?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-fields, capacitance

Consider a spherical capacitor, that is, two concentrical spherical shells which serve as plates. Suppose the capacitor is charged. It is my understanding that the energy stored by a capacitor is actually stored in the electric field between the plates. The electric field between the two spherical shells of the system at hand is equal to the electric field produced by the inner shell, which only depends on the charge on the inner shell. This is all proved via Gaussian surfaces. Then, does the spherical capacitor store as much energy as its inner shell would if the outer shell weren't there? If so, why do we need the second shell at all? Am I missing or misinterpreting something?

Comment: How are you proposing to charge the single shell?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to connect it with the positive electrode of a battery?

Comment: You'll certainly get some positive charge on the shell, but not as much as you'd get if you connected a capacitor of two concentric shells across the battery. If you could get equal charges on the lone shell and the inner shell of the two-electrode capacitor, your energy comparison would be correct.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, capacitors are easier to charge than single conductors? Does it mean that less energy is required to charge them with the same amount of charge? If so, could you point out the physical principle behind this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It's not, I think, a matter of energy. It's more a matter of getting points at infinity (or even just points a long way from the shell) at the same potential as the negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: And how does a second shell help with that?

Comment: You simply connect the second (outer) shell to the other terminal of the battery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacitance is a quantity that is related to the amount of work (the potential difference)that must be done on a charge to physically bring it from a point infinitely far away (assumed to be at zero potential) to the object in question. As such, there is no need to postulate the outer shell in order for the inner shell to exhibit an electric field, a potential difference (with respect to an arbitrary point infinitely far away), or a capacitance. Which is why it is possible to calculate the capacitance of the earth (and all electrical engineering students are asked to do this).

However, if the hypothetical charge in question does not originate at infinity, but originates from the outer shell, then the total work done on that charge to bring it to the innner shell is less. Which is another way of saying that the capacitance of the inner/outer shell scenario is increased by the presence of the outer shell.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very insightful.